# Example of a Manifold which has One Non-zero Component of Ric which equals the Scalar Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am wondering if there is a simple example of a manifold such that, given a value for the scalar curvature $R$, I can find a manifold such that the Ricci tensor has all zero components except for one component which takes the value $R$.

I know this could be achieved using a warped product of two metrics to separate out one coordinate and then solve the differential equations so that the first coefficient vanishes, but obviously the coefficient of the non-zero component needs to be $R$.

Comment: To be clear, do you mean that you have a smooth function $R$ and want a metric $g$ and coordinates $(x_1, \ldots, x_{n - 1}, y)$ for which the Ricci curvature of $g$ is $R \,dy^2$, or a metric and coordinates for which the Ricci curvature has the form $\phi \,dy^2$ and whose scalar curvature is $R$? In general these are different things. (One could ask for metrics that satisfy both, but that's not very natural, I think.)

Comment: The first one, basically given a value for the scalar curvature I would like an example of a manifold such that $\text{Ric}(g)=R dy^2$.

Comment: I've written up an answer, but your description motivates me to warn you that mentioning "scalar curvature" in that context is a little misleading, as in general the scalar curvature of the metric will not coincide with $R$. Indeed, in the example in my answer the scalar curvature is $G^{-1} R$.

Comment: Is there some example of a manifold where the scalar curvature does always coincide with $R$?

Comment: Sure, that's actually the case for the examples in my answer to your other question, because there the metric has the form of the metric in this answer with $G \equiv 1$. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3153780/155629 But asking for that component with respect to some frame to coincide with $R$ isn't very geometrically natural, so I'd guess that's not what you're really looking for here.

Comment: So in the example you gave you can't really have it that you have an explicit value for the scalar curvature, as you would have to invert $G$?  Why is it that the scalar curvature is $G^{-1}R$?

Comment: I might be missing something here, is there some general reason why you can't just assume a value for scalar curvature of the manifold and have it that the Ricci tensor has one component equal to that scalar curvature with respect to some coordinate choice?

Comment: No, like I said, the condition the one you asked for ("The first one..."). The scalar curvature of a metric $h$ is the contraction $h^{ab} \operatorname{Ric}_{ab}$, so if $\operatorname{Ric} = R \,dy^2$ and the coefficient of $\partial_y \otimes \partial_y$ is $A$ then contracting gives that the scalar curvature is $A R$. For the example in my answer $A = G^{-1}$, so the scalar curvature is $G^{-1} R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reasonably explicit construction, similar to the one in [my answer to your related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3153780/155629), that works in some cases, namely when $R$ is strictly positive and we work in a neighborhood of any point not critical for $R$. The latter condition guarantees that there are coordinates $(x_1, \ldots, x_{n - 1}, y)$ for which $R$ is a function of $y$ alone.

If we take $\bar g := \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} dx^i \otimes dx^i$ (the standard Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^{n - 1}$) and $dy^2$ to be the standard metric on $\Bbb R$, then the Ricci tensor of 
$$g := F(y) \bar g + G(y) dy^2$$
is
$$\operatorname{Ric} = \frac{2 F'' F G - F' G' F + (n - 3) (F')^2 G}{4 F G^2} \bar g - \frac{3 (2 F'' - (F')^2 G - F' G' F)}{F^2 G} dy^2 .$$

We want this to coincide with $R \,dy^2$ for some scalar function $R$, which amounts to asking (1) that the coefficient of $\bar g$ vanish and (2) the coefficient of $dy^2$ be our prescribed function $R$.

This is a nonlinear system of two o.d.e.s in unknown functions $F, G$, but we can still solve it as explicitly as one might hope. The solutions are given by
$$F(y) = C \exp \left[\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{(n - 1) (n - 2)}} \int_{y_0}^y \sqrt{R(t)} \,dt\right], \quad G(y) = C F'(y)^2 F(y)^{n - 3}, \quad C \in \Bbb R,$$ and this defines a metric if $C > 0$.

Comment: Is it possible to solve the two ODEs semi-explicitly if you require the coefficient of gbar to be some real constant $A$ and the coefficient of $dy^2$ to be some other real constant $B$?

Comment: Yes, you can find the general solution, in fact, but it's a little unpleasant. To be clear, there are many other ways to construct examples of the sorts of metrics and coordinates you're asking about, but a warped product of flat metrics is a good place to look for explicitly computable examples.

Comment: I was hoping to find a general solution but had some trouble with it when I tried to do it on the computer which made me think it might be unpleasant: I was hoping for something that could be written down on a line. As long as it is explicit I don't think it matters too much, I essentially just need to know that a explicit solution exists and can be written down.

Comment: Maple gives $$F \left( y \right) =1/3\,{\frac {{3}^{2/3}{2}^{2/3}\sqrt [3]{B}{
{\rm e}^{1/3\,\sqrt {3}\sqrt {B}y}}}{ \left( {{\rm e}^{\sqrt {3}\sqrt 
{B}y}}{\it \_C1}-{\it \_C2} \right) ^{2/3}}}, \qquad
G \left( y \right) =-1/3\,{\frac {{3}^{2/3}{2}^{2/3}{{\rm e}^{4/3\,
\sqrt {3}\sqrt {B}y}}{B}^{4/3}{\it \_C1}\,{\it \_C2}}{ \left( {{\rm e}
^{\sqrt {3}\sqrt {B}y}}{\it \_C1}-{\it \_C2} \right) ^{8/3}A}}.
$$ The case $A \neq 0$ must be handled separately.

Comment: Hmm, yes that's a bit uglier than I was hoping for although technically it doesn't matter, what does the _ mean in front of the constants?

Comment: That's just a prefix Maple uses for the arbitrary constants it generates when solving equations. You should be able to improve the appearance of the solution some by choosing $\texttt{_C1}, \texttt{_C2}$ judiciously.

Comment: Hang on, how did you solve this with Maple, when I tried I didn't get something which had exponentials in it and had some technical difficulties trying to solve the system.  Obviously don't go into the details if there isn't room.

Comment: I'm just curious how you solved it, as its a coupled nonlinear system, so it's definitely not trivial to plug it into Maple.

Comment: NB the above solution is for the typical case $n = 5$. You can generate the solution with the following Maple code:

```restart;
with(DifferentialGeometry): with(Tensor):
n := 5;
vars := seq(x||i, i=1..(n - 1)), y;
DGsetup([vars], M);
g := evalDG(F(y) * add(dx||i &t dx||i, i = 1..(n - 1)) + G(y) * dy &t dy);
RicciTensor(g):
[Hook([D_x1, D_x1], %) - A, Hook([D_y, D_y], %) - B];
simplify(dsolve(%), symbolic);
simplify([%[1][1], eval(%[2][1], %[1][1])], symbolic);```

Comment: When I try n = 3, it seems like the code gives two different solutions, is this reflecting whether constants can be negative or positive or something like that?

Comment: Yes, that's usually what that behavior means.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a simple example, I was curious about what happens for a 2D manifold. Let's try to fix the Ricci scalar $R$ to be some value $S$. (Note that it is twice the Gaussian curvature in this case $K$, i.e. $R = 2K$).

In 2D, we have (see: [[1]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77973/riemann-tensor-in-2d-and-3d), [[2]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-the-connection-and-the-curvature-tensor), [[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Special_cases)):
\begin{align}
 R_{abcd} &= \frac{R}{2}(g_{ac}g_{bd} - g_{ad}g_{bc}) \\
R_{\alpha\gamma} &= g^{mn} R_{n\alpha m\gamma} \\
       &= g^{mn}\frac{R}{2}(g_{ac}g_{bd} - g_{ad}g_{bc}) \\
       &= \frac{R}{2}(2g_{\alpha\gamma} - \delta^m_\gamma g_{\alpha m}) \\
       &= Kg_{\alpha\gamma} \\
R &= \text{tr}_g (\text{Ric})=g^{ij}R_{ij} = 2K
\end{align}
You are requiring two constraints:

1. $S = R$
2. Every component of $R_{ij}$ is zero except one.

Notice that in this case you are requiring every entry of the metric tensor to be zero except one entry (which must be on the diagonal, since $g$ is symmetric) that must equal $1$. Such a metric is not invertible (nor positive definite)!

I guess in 2D, asking for this is too harsh of a constraint on the metric tensor.

Comment: Indeed, you've shown for a Riemannian surface that $\operatorname{Ric}$ is a multiple of $g$, so at each point $p$, $\operatorname{Ric}_p$ has full rank or is the zero tensor.